# htaccess rewrite rule for javascript file with multiple periods

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm looking for a rewrite rule that will handle a request such as

```
js/mysite/jquery.somelibrary.js or
js/mysite/jquery.validate.js or
js/mysite/somejsfile.js
```

What I have written so far handles the last case
    `RewriteRule ^js/([a-z_]+)/([^\/.]+)\.js$ /site_specific_js.php?site=$1&file=$2 [QSA,L]`

but on the first two, all that gets rewritten for the file
is **jquery** and everything else gets ignored

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All things is on te dot `([^\/.]+)`, just remove it

```
RewriteRule ^js/([a-z_]+)/([^\/]+)\.js$ /site_specific_js.php?site=$1&file=$2 [QSA,L]
```

or as in the $1

```
RewriteRule ^js/([a-z_]+)/([a-z0-9\.]+)\.js$ /site_specific_js.php?site=$1&file=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
RewriteRule ^js/([a-z_]+)/([^\/.]+)\.js$ /site_specific_js.php?site=$1&file=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Let's look at the filename, which is the important part:

```
([^\/.]+)\.js
```

Escaping the forward-slash isn't needed, since we're not using delimiters in our regex. Indeed, you use `/` unescaped elsewhere.

```
([^/.]+)\.js
```

Let's break it down:

```
(
  [^    # anything that's not:
    /   # a forward slash, or
    .   # a period
  ]  
  +     # one or more times
)  
\.      # then a period
js      # then "js"
```

Clearly, we can just remove `.` from the character class:

```
(
  [^    # anything that's not:
    /   # a forward slash
  ]  
  +     # one or more times
)
\.      # then a period
js      # then "js"
```

Ending up with:

```
RewriteRule ^js/([a-z_]+)/([^/]+)\.js$ /site_specific_js.php?site=$1&file=$2 [QSA,L]
```